# How to get form property in a user task in activiti7?

Tags: java, spring-boot, activiti

I'm now using activiti7 with spring-boot2, but there are some problems trouble me.

In activiti6 or activiti5, I can user FormService to get form property of a task, but in activiti7, I can not autowire FormService, can any one tell me how to get form property of a task in activiti7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In activiti 7 we are going full for cloud deployments, meaning that the responsibility of the different components is now decoupled. We chose to start with the core elements for that reason the Form Service is not longer available in the core library and it will be provided as a separate service later on. 
For now you can link your tasks to UI/Pages using the Task-formKey property.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the solution ? I don't get how to retrieve form properties through the task or anything else.

Comment: That means that you cannot do that with 7

Comment: @salaboy - Is the Form service / forms creation now available as of today through any means?

Comment: I don’t think so